# Template specific fields, BoltCMS

Tags: bolt-cms

Template specific fields dont work for me, the additional fields dont appear when selecting the template. I tried restarting nginx, checking the database and clearing the cache, but that didn't work.

config.yml (indentation changed when copy-pasting):

```
templatefields:
tochten.twig:
    section_1_heading:
        type: text
    section_1_body:
        type: html
    section_2_heading:
        type: text
    section_2_body:
        type: html
```

And this is the contenttype I am using with the template specific fields (indentation, changed when copy-pasting):

```
paginas:
name: Paginas
singular_name: Pagina
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        class: large
    heading:
        type: text
        class: large
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: title
    image:
        type: image
        upload: paginas
        extensions: [ jpg ]
    body:
        type: html
    template:
        type: templateselect
        filter: '*.twig'
default_status: publish
sort: -datepublish
```

Edit: BoltCMS version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of Bolt? It's only supported on [2.2 onward](https://docs.bolt.cm/building-templates#building-templates-live-editor).

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version, 2.2.1